# How can I get a dryad in my village?

Tags: terraria

I already build new home for her but nothing happens.I have 18 gold(if that matters) but no one moves into the new home. In my village I already have 4 NPCs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the dryad to move in, you must have killed at least one boss ([Eye of Cthulhu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eye_of_Cthulhu), [Eater of Worlds](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eater_of_Worlds), [Brain of Cthulhu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Brain_of_Cthulhu), or [Skeletron](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Skeletron)). (see [the wiki page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad) for more information)

Eye of Cthulhu is the easiest. If you want to fight him now, bring 6 [lens](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lens)es to a [Demon Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Altar) or [Crimson Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Altar), craft a [Suspicious Looking Eye](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Suspicious_Looking_Eye), and use it at night.

Comment: Defeating the Brain of Cthulu will also encourage the Dryad to move in.

Comment: @EtherDragon Yep, good point, I keep forgetting about all the new content :D